# Enviar de archivos pdf con input file mediante ajax, jquery, sin recargar página

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Requiero enviar archivos pdf al servidor sin recargar, desde la captura del formulario la cual la petición la proceso de la siguiente forma.

Mediante la siguiente función registrarActa() en jquery, cabe mencionar que aquí obtengo los datos del formulario para poder procesarlos con el formData.

```
function registrarActa(){
let identidadusuario = $("#identidadusuario").val();
let archivoActa = $("#fileActa").val();

if(archivoActa.length == 0 || identidadusuario == "" ){
     swal({
        title: "¡ Debes de seleccionar PDF de Acta de Nacimiento o Elegir Empleado!",
        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonText: "¡Cerrar!"
    });
     return;
}

let formData = new FormData();
let actaNacimiento = $("#fileActa")[0].files[0];
let folioEmpleado = $("#folioEmpleado").val();

formData.append('actaNacimiento', actaNacimiento);
formData.append('folioEmpleado', folioEmpleado);
formData.append('identidadusuario', identidadusuario);

$.ajax({
    url:'ajax/documentacion.ajax.php',
    type:'post',
    data:formData,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend:function(){
        $("#loaderActa").fadeIn('slow');
        $('#loaderActa').html('<img src="vistas/img/plantilla/ajax-loader.gif">');  
    },
    success:function(respuesta){
        console.log("respuesta", respuesta);
    }
});
    return false;
}
```

Llamo el ajax(**ajax/documentacion.ajax.php**) lo cual comprende, el proceso de renombrar el pdf y mover el pdf, mi detalle es que no procesa la función `if(move_uploaded_file($nacimiento["tmp_name"], $ruta.$renombre)).` tal que me retorna error en este if, que creen que me haga falta.

```
<?php 
    require_once "../controladores/documentacion.controlador.php";
    require_once "../modelos/documentacion.modelo.php";
       

class AjaxDocumentacion{

    public $identidadusuario;
    public $folioEmpleado;
    public $actaNacimiento;

    public function ajaxAgregarActaNacimiento(){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
        $idEmpleado = $this->identidadusuario;
        $claveIdentidad = $this->folioEmpleado;
        $nacimiento = $this->actaNacimiento;
        $renombre = "Nacimiento-".$claveIdentidad."-".date("YmdHsi").".pdf";
        $ruta = "vistas/img/empleados/".$claveIdentidad."/";
        rename ($nacimiento["name"], $renombre);
        if(is_array($nacimiento) && count($nacimiento) > 0){

            if(move_uploaded_file($nacimiento["tmp_name"], $ruta.$renombre)){
                echo json_encode("ok");
            }else{
                echo json_encode("error");
            }
        }
    }

}

if(isset($_POST["identidadusuario"])){
    $altaActa = new AjaxDocumentacion();
    $altaActa -> identidadusuario = $_POST["identidadusuario"];
    $altaActa -> folioEmpleado = $_POST["folioEmpleado"]; 
    $altaActa -> actaNacimiento = $_FILES["actaNacimiento"];
    $altaActa -> ajaxAgregarActaNacimiento();

}


 ?>
```

En en proceso de la función de jQuery si me envia los parametros del formData, pero al procesarlo en php en la clase y el método no me permite pasar el input file (pdf)

Comment: tengo una respuesta a una pregunta parecida a la tuya, puedes revisar en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/586415/como-enviar-formulario-con-una-imagen-y-otros-campos-a-api-php/586584#586584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré mi solución, solo me faltaba el directorio raiz `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` con eso quedo, les dejo el ejemplo completo, por si alguien le llega servir, saludos.

```
public $identidadusuario;
public $folioEmpleado;
public $actaNacimiento;

public function ajaxAgregarActaNacimiento(){

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

    $idEmpleado = $this->identidadusuario;
    $claveIdentidad = $this->folioEmpleado;
    $nacimiento = $this->actaNacimiento;
    $renombre = "Acta-Nacimiento-".$claveIdentidad."-".date("ymdHsi").".pdf";


    $ruta = "vistas/img/empleados/".$claveIdentidad."/";
    $fichero = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$ruta;

    rename ($nacimiento["name"], $renombre);

    if(is_array($nacimiento) && count($nacimiento) > 0){

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["actaNacimiento"]["tmp_name"], $fichero.$renombre)){

            echo json_encode("ok");

        }else{
            echo json_encode("error");
        
        }
     }

}

 if(isset($_POST["identidadusuario"])){
    $altaActa = new AjaxDocumentacion();
    $altaActa -> identidadusuario = $_POST["identidadusuario"];
    $altaActa -> folioEmpleado = $_POST["folioEmpleado"]; 
    $altaActa -> actaNacimiento = $_FILES["actaNacimiento"];
    $altaActa -> ajaxAgregarActaNacimiento();
}
```